# Spring. Проблема с кодировкой в jsp при submit формы

Tags: spring, jsp

Есть jsp файл с формой:
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    ...
    
    ...
    
    ...

Файл jsp имеет кодировку UTF-8.

При submit приезжает поломанный текст - кракозябы.

1. Как текст "заголовок" выводится вот такая хрень: "Ð·Ð°Ð³Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ðº"
   В браузере отображается utf-8.
2. Использую БД h2, там вроде utf по умолчанию.
3. Конвертер правильно декодирует через кодировку ISO-8859-5
4. "Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" on your  in server.xml." - это сделал, не помогает.
5. Все исходники: https://github.com/AndrewBryukhov/ClassicWebApplication страница edit.jsp
6. Наблюдается под opera & ie & firefox
7. Под отладчиком я вижу что кривые данные приезжают с браузера.

Пришлось сделать временное исправление, но оно мне не нравится, т.к. не решает причину:
    byte[] isoBytes = author.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    author = new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8");
Еще странный момент нашел. При ошибке на сервере, tomcat выдает мой jsp с поврежденными кириллическими текстами, хотя страница отображается в utf8. При их декодировании конвертер говорит что это utf8.

Добавление в ConfigurationAdapter:
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");

```
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

не помогло ((

Проблема не в БД т.к. кривые данные приезжают со стороны браузера. Видимо дело в jsp или tomcat.
Так что вопрос актуален.

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать везде utf-8 и написать для начала в web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Если не поможет добавь рецепт:
http://elwood.su/2012/08/spring-responsebody-%D0%B8-utf-8/